# NodeJS Docker image failing to build

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to migrate from Node v16 to v18 but when I deploy, the ECS task fails the health checks. Upon looking at the logs, I see no errors. Output below:

```
npm WARN config `_auth`, `_authToken`, `username` and `_password` must be scoped to a registry. See `npm help npmrc` for more
> NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 && node dist/server
> @hello/some_repo@2.1.0-branch start
npm notice
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.0.0` to update!
npm notice Changelog:
npm notice New major version of npm available!
npm notice
```

This is where the task ends and fails.

Fails locally as well. Looked into my local docker build and found that the node version was indeed updated to 18 but is unable to run. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Fails locally as well" Then it's not really an AWS/ECS issue at all.

Comment: Would you please share your Dockerfile as well?